# AG Data Grid - How to handle capitalized fields returned by remote site?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using React - AG Grid. From remote site, I am getting columns like Name, Type - Capitalized. However, the ColumnDefs needs all lowercase fields in `useState`, else the table does not show the values fetched from the remote site. How to handle? ...

```
  const [columnDefs] = useState([
    {field: 'name'}, {field: 'type'} // remote site gives Name, Type
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *headerName* property in columndef. you can refer [Accessing Row Data Values](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-definitions/#accessing-row-data-values)

here is an example code:

```
const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
{ headerName: 'name', field: 'Name'},
{ headerName: 'type', field: 'Type'},
]);
```